# SQL - дубликаты записи

Tags: mysql, python, sql

при парсинге магазинов у товаров возникает одна проблема:

В случае если магазина нету в базе данных, то он добавляется в него.
При работе в несколько потоков возникает иногда ситуация:

У нескольких товаров (1 поток, под каждый товар) может иметь один и тот же магазин, и если этого магазина нет, то они одновременно добавляют одну и ту же запись в бд, хотя проверка на наличие этого магазина есть.

Как можно обойти эту проблему? Может как нибудь сделать совокупность несколько столбцов уникальными? (можно ли вообще так сделать?)

Проблема возникает именно, когда работает несколько потоков, чем больше, тем больше записей может добавиться.
При работе в 1 поток проблемы нет.

Код

```
sql = """SELECT id FROM shop WHERE company=%s and name=%s and address=%s and locality_id=%s and class=%s"""
data = [(company, name_shop, address_shop, city_id, "1")]
print(data)
row = select_request_db(sql,data)
log.info("Выборка")
if(len(row)==1):
  shop_id = row [0]
else:
  if(len(row)==0):
     sql = """INSERT INTO shop(class,company,name,address,locality_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s)"""
     data = [("1",company,name_shop,address_shop,city_id)]
     shop_id= insert_request_db (sql,data)
     log.info("Добавление")
  else:
     print("Ошибка")
     exit(0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала в один поток добавить все магазины?

Comment: @insolor спасибо за идею

Comment: сделать на таблице уникальный ключ из тех полей, по которым вы сейчас ищете магазин перед добавлением. после чего использовать `insert ignore into ...`